# How can I know a number of uploaded files with PHP?

Tags: php, upload

I have a form with several

```
input type="file"
```

tags. How can I know on the server side amount of files uploaded by the user. He can upload 3 files, or may be 5 files, 1 or even nothing. I need to know how much files user have uploaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are having input upload tags with name like `file1`, `file2` then

```
if($_FILES['file1']['size'] > 0)
    echo "User uploaded some file for the input named file1"
```

Now for many files (looking at the output you are having), run a foreach loop like this:-

```
$cnt=0;
foreach($_FILES as $eachFile)
{
     if($eachFile['size'] > 0)
        $cnt++;
}
echo $cnt." files uploaded";
```

I am not sure why the similar answer in [How can I know a number of uploaded files with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368107/how-can-i-know-a-number-of-uploaded-files-with-php-closed) got downvoted? For the '0' ?

Comment: $_FILES has the files based on name and any input that has multiple files from the same named input or an array[] syntax will not be counted in your code.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `count` or `sizeof` on `$_FILES` array that contains uploaded file info:

```
 echo count($_FILES);
```

---

### Update (Based on comments):

You can do this:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($_FILES as $value){
  if (strlen($value['name'])){
    $counter++;
  }
}

echo $counter; // get files count
```

Comment: it displays "1" every time :) even if no files uploaded.

Comment: @user337085: That should not be the case, are you refreshing the page with POST data? You can test things out with `print_r($_FILES)` :)

Comment: It's OK, but it displays the total number of the input fields. For example, if I have 3 fields and upload only two files, it displays 3. And says that the third file wasn't uploaded.

Comment: print_r output is: ( [Picture1] => Array ( [name] => 16.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => Z:\tmp\php92A5.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 29175 ) [Picture2] => Array ( [name] => 2010-10-02_135854.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => Z:\tmp\php92A6.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 1035911 ) [Picture3] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: This means first file was OK, seconds was OK, third was not uploaded. And count($_FILES) returns 3. But the correct value is 2.

Comment: You can see what's in the array, so you should have the answer to your question now. Count how many elements of $_FILES have a filename/size/no error.

Comment: Is there any gentle way of doing that? Would you share a code snippet if possible, please.

Answer (score 2):

`$_FILES` is a global array of files which stores uploaded files.

Answer (score 1):

**Form:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ...>
<input type="file" name="image[]" multiple>
```

**Script:**

```
$c = sizeof($_FILES['image']['name']);
```

Comment: Explain your script a bit to improve the answer. Script only answers are discouraged.

Comment: $_FILES is an array, so i used sizeof to count the elements of the array.