# How can I know a number of uploaded files with PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I know a number of uploaded files with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367861/how-can-i-know-a-number-of-uploaded-files-with-php)

Hello, I have a form with three

```
input type="file"
```

tags. **How can I know on the server side amount of files uploaded by the user?** He can upload 3 files, or may be 2 files, 1 or even nothing. I need to know how much files user have uploaded.

If I use the code

```
echo count($_FILES);
```

It will always display the value of 3. Because form contains three file fields. If the user will upload only two files, the code will display 3, but the right value is 2.

Comment: You just asked this! Edit your previous question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Please do not ask duplicates.

Comment: sorry, it's hard to receive the right answer when a lot of people already agreed with wrong solution. Cos people don't look old topics here.

Comment: @user337085: Still doesn't mean it's OK to ask duplicates. Ignoring the community rules is not going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$count=0;
foreach($_FILES as $file){
if ($file["size"]>'0')$count++;
}
```