# how to get number of results from a loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

i have a upload script to upload some files to a directory. every file runs through a loop and will be checked if there are errors with the size or ending or even not. in case of no error it will be uploaded.

```
if (is_array($_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'])) {
    foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $val ) {
        ...

        if (! in_array ( $fileExt, $allowedExtensions )) {
            $errors [$fileName] [] = "format not accepted";
        }...

            if ((count ( $errors1 ) == 0) && (count ( $errors ) === 0))  {
               if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                //...                               
            }
        }   
     }
}
```

my question is, is there a way to count the number of the uploaded files that successfully ran through that loop? thanks a lot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367861/how-can-i-know-a-number-of-uploaded-files-with-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count each successful upload.

like below:

```
   if (is_array($_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'])) {
    $Counter=0;     // initialize counter variable
        foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $val ) {

            $fileName = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key];
            $fileSize = $_FILES ['image'] ['size'] [$key];
            $fileTemp = $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] [$key];

            $fileExt = pathinfo ( $fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            $fileExt = strtolower ( $fileExt );

            if (empty ( $fileName ))
            continue;

            if (! in_array ( $fileExt, $allowedExtensions )) {
                $errors [$fileName] [] = "format not accepted";
            }...

                if ((count ( $errors1 ) == 0) && (count ( $errors ) === 0))  {
                   if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
                    //...           
                   $Counter++;       // increment if successful upload
                }
            }   
         }
    }

echo $Counter;  //it will give total count of successfully uploaded files
```

Comment: thats the way i was looking for. amazing how simple it is. thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a counter variable. I understand you have uploaded a file successfully when `move_uploaded_file` returns true, right?

```
$counter = 0;
//... your code
if ((count ( $errors1 ) == 0) && (count ( $errors ) === 0))  {
    if (move_uploaded_file ( $fileTemp, $fileDst )) {
        $counter++;
        //... some other code
    }
}
```

So, when you leave the `foreach` loop `$counter` will have the expected value.